# How to return values from the same field across multiple Quote Lines

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

Hope you're all having a really great day!

In a recent build, I was tasked with printing a warning message when a subscriber's quote includes a mobile transfer (Mobile_Transfer__c = `true`). In testing everything looked good, with a simple condition. However, where the following scenario is met, the script will only return the first result and suppress the email content:

- Quoteline 1: Mobile_Transfer__c = `false`
- Quoteline 2: Mobile_Transfer__c = `false`
- Quoteline 3: Mobile_Transfer__c = `true`

In the above scenario, we have three mobile services on the quote with one of these being a transfer service, which means I need to print the `transfer content`.

Here's the existing script:

```
set @quoteLineRowSet = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "SBQQ__QuoteLine__c",
"Id,Mobile_Transfer_Date__c,Mobile_Transfer__c,"
if RowCount(@quoteLineRowSet) > 1 then /*if multiple records are found then loop through each record*/
 for @i = 1 to RowCount(@quoteLineRowSet) do
   set @quoteLine = row(@quoteLineRowSet, @i)

   if @productFamily == "Mobile" then
    set @hasMobile = "True"
    if @productType == "Plan" then
     set @mobileTransfer = field(@quoteLine,"Mobile_Transfer__c")
     set @mobileTransferDate = field(@quoteLine,"Mobile_Transfer_Date__c")
     set @mobileStartDate = field(@quoteLine,"SBQQ__StartDate__c")
      if indexOf(@mobileTransfer,"TRUE") > 0 then
         set @hasMobileTransfer="1"
      endif
    endif
```

Note: there are other products that are looped through (I've removed these to look at the mobile product specifically.

The dynamic content is wrapped in the following AMPscript block:

```
%%[if @hasMobileTransfer == '1' then]%%
The dynamic content
%%[endif]%%
```

Any help or thoughts on a simpler solution would be very much appreciated. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Hi, 1) Why are you using `indexOf(@mobileTransfer,"TRUE") > 0` towards the bottom, and not `== TRUE` as before? 2) Can you edit your question and show an output example what this means exactly: "where the following scenario is met, the script will only return the first result and suppress the email content:" - I don't quite understand the problem, are you seeing just one loop result instead of an expected three results? Can you print `%%=v(@i)=%%` to see which loop result(s) are printed? Are you sure it's #1? 3) Your retrieve function ends on a comma, and your first if statement doesn't close?